# Why not always use _express-checkout-mobile for Paypal Express Checkout?

Tags: paypal

In PayPal Express Checkout, `_express-checkout-mobile` seems to auto-detect the browser and show the correct page at all times.

Are there scenarios where the mobile UI will be improperly displayed? Is there a reason to ever pass `_express-checkout` instead?

Answer (score 0):

I've always used _express-checkout and it automatically detects which experience to use.  I think if you use _express-checkout-mobile it will use the mobile experience regardless of the platform the user is on, but I haven't tested that specifically.

Comment: That's strange - I have the exact opposite experience. _express-checkout always takes people to the desktop version, but _express-checkout-mobile picks the correct one automatically.

Comment: What API version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested it with _express_checkout, and on my mobile phone I am forwarded to the mobile payment design.

There does not seem to be a difference.